# How many SQLite DB files can be opened at a time in an OS?

Tags: c++, sqlite, file, file-io, limit

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425084/how-many-files-can-i-have-opened-at-once) suggests the limit for the number of files open-able in few OSs. And as per [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux), the number of files in Linux can be changed.

In an app written in C++, I am opening several SQLite database files using `sqlite3_open_v2()` at a time for several users' DBs; there is no `fstream` in this.
I was curious to know, what is the file limit for SQLite DB files? Is it the same as normal files or are they treated differently.

**Add-on**: Suppose the file number is limited; in such case, what is the correct design to open-close such .db files without impacting much performance?

Comment: Why do you open several databases, in the first place? And why so many that you max out limits? How big are the databases? Why not attaching/merging them?

Comment: A typical default for the number of open file descriptors a single process can have is 1024. This can be adjusted if needed, but if you're in danger of running out of descriptors from opening a ton of databases (Depending on settings it'll take something like 1 to 3 per database)... you might need to rethink your approach - a design that doesn't require so many databases, a different approach, etc. This smells like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...